# Shared folder on Mac

Tags: macos, posix, acl

The default **Shared** folder in MacOSX does not seem to live up to its name. Sure, all users on the local Mac can create folders and add files to the **Shared** folder, however other users cannot open the files or make any changes, unless it is files & folders they created/added.

Using the permissions GUI (ACLs and POSIX), I failed to find a solution to my needs which are essentially to make the **Shared** folder a place where all local Mac users (or a subset of users) have full permissions.

I am hoping that someone would have a suggestion.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the GUI; it doesn't allow you to control (or even see) some of the necessary settings. So you need to use the Terminal, and run some `chmod` (change "mode", i.e. change permissions), and you need to use `sudo` to run them with root permissions (note that `sudo` will prompt for your admin password to allow this, but the password won't echo as you type). Also, be careful with these commands (or anything else involving `sudo`) -- the specific commands I'll give you should be safe, but if you change the wrong permission on the wrong file, you can completely break the OS.

You need to do two things: remove the "sticky" bit (which prevents users from deleting/moving/renaming other users' files):

```
sudo chmod -t /Users/Shared
```

Then add an inheritable ACL granting everyone full read+write access. The Finder's Get Info window will let you add ACLs, but not control inheritance, so again you use `sudo chmod` ... and include a long list of exactly what types of file access need to be allowed:

```
sudo chmod +a "group:everyone list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Users/Shared
```